# Run code only once for every new session in the same class

Tags: objective-c

I wanted to run a piece of code for only once, for a session, and then run once again on new session after a reset. First thing came to my mind was `dispatch_once_f`, but I needs to be able to control it in each session, and for multiple pieces of code that should store the once tokens in a dictionary (dynamically generated, rather than statically allocate as global variable). The idea (pseudocode) is something similar to this:

```
static myCodeBlockOne(){
//Do something for step1
}

static myCodeBlockTwo(){
//Do something for step2
}

//Initialize the class ivars
_aDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

//In a new session
_aDictionary[@"step1"] = (dispatch_once_t )0; //this will return error however
_aDictionary[@"step2"] = (dispatch_once_t )0;
dispatch_once_f(&_aDictionary[@"step1"], NULL, myCodeBlockOne); //this too
dispatch_once_f(&_aDictionary[@"step2"], NULL, myCodeBlockTwo);

//Reset session and the tokens so that as if the code for steps 1&2 never run, and the code above should be able to run once more
_aDictionary[@"step1"] = (dispatch_once_t )0; 
_aDictionary[@"step2"] = (dispatch_once_t )0;
```

Any idea how to properly implement this idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about some flags and `if`s?

Comment: Yeah, for now I resolved to flags, seems to do the work. But would interesting to see if anyone actually manage to strictly using the `dispatch_once_f`.